# Why Container Query is not recognised in vscode

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, container-queries

[image]

Unknown at rule @containercss(unknownAtRules)
Unknown property: 'container-type'css(unknownProperties)
Unknown property: 'container-name'css(unknownProperties)

Comment: @container is still not fully supported in all browsers...so that may be the main reason. Also: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/170589

Comment: If you want, you can install and use stylelint as the default validator and formatter for css and sass and then VS code will support these new features.  It's a work-around while VS code updates their formatter.  But you may find you like it better since stylelint has useful plugins like stylelint-config-idiomatic-order and stylelint-config-standard-scss

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Container-type property and @container rule are not recognized by VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76125833/container-type-property-and-container-rule-are-not-recognized-by-vs-code)

Answer (score -4):

If you use @container with the extension .scss visual won't show the warning

Comment: It does show the warning for me. Maybe that's because I'm editing .scss file that's inside Angular application?