# Container-type property and @container rule are not recognized by VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was trying to create a card and modify its behavior with the container-type property and the @container rule that in caniuse says it's supported but VS Code doesn't recognize them, anyone knows why and/or how to fixed?

[Reference Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ly3iL.jpg)

I'm not really sure what should I do, I checked https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Container_Queries but didn't found an specific answer.

I also tried to activate it from chrome lab ----> chrome://flags/ but since it's supposed to be supported doesn't appear there.

Please keep in mind that I'm still learning CSS.

Answer (score 7):

#### VS Code 1.85+ answer

It's partially supported now in the CSS and SASS/SCSS language modes.

For the SASS/SCSS change, see [fix layer and container in scss #371](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-css-languageservice/pull/371).

#### VS Code 1.84 answer

It's partially supported now in the CSS language mode, but not yet in the SASS/SCSS language mode. For that, see issue ticket [[scss] Error when parsing container queries with interpolation #197744](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/197744).

Support for `@container` was added by [support @container, prepare 6.2.10
#365](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-css-languageservice/pull/365), which will be released in VS Code 1.84 ([source](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-css-languageservice/pull/365#issuecomment-1759099713)).

#### VS Code 1.83 answer

It's partially supported now in the CSS language mode, but not yet in the SASS/SCSS language mode. Support for `@container` is pending.

See Pull Request [Add support for container, container-name, and container-type.
#14](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-css/pull/14), which has been merged. Also see Pull Request [Update CSS grammar #193333](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/193333), which adds properties like `container`, `container-name`, and `container-type` to the CSS grammar.

#### VS Code Pre-1.83 answer

This is an open issue in the VS Code backlog. See [[css] Support CSS property `container-type` #170589](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/170589) ([[css] Support @container css rule #179314](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/179314) is closed in favour of tracking the overarching issue there).

In the meantime, you can work around the issue by using [VS Code's custom data mechanism](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-css-languageservice/blob/main/docs/customData.md). Create a JSON file in your workspace folder with the following contents (or optionally reuse an existing one that you've created for other purposes):

```json
{
  "version": 1.1,
  "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/vscode-css-languageservice/main/docs/customData.schema.json",
  "atDirectives": [
    {
      "name": "@container",
      "description": "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Container_Queries"
    }
  ],
  "properties": [
    {
      "name": "container-type",
      "description": "https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/container-type"
    },
    {
      "name": "container-name",
      "description": "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/container-name"
    },
    {
      "name": "container",
      "description": "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/container"
    }
  ]
}
```

And then in your workspace `.vscode/settings.json` file, add the following:

```json
"css.customData": [
   "css-container-custom-data.json"
   // ^ whatever the name/path of your custom data file is
],
```

I also suggest you see [this improved version](https://github.com/wileycoyote78/custom-css/blob/main/.vscode/custom-css.json) by [wileyCoyote](/users/1478850).

Comment: This answer rocks! Except the schema URL is wrong. It should be: `"$schema": https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/vscode-css-languageservice/master/docs/customData.schema.json` I also created a repo with "starter files" following this method; just download and place the folder in your wrokspace's .vscode folder.

Comment: @wileyCoyote there's no master branch. granted, the URL I originally wrote redirects to https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/vscode-css-languageservice/main/docs/customData.schema.json, so I've updated the answer post for that.

Comment: The only reason I said the schema link was wrong was because VS Code complained at me about it and wasn't applying the schema. The only reason I found the "correct" one was because when I started typing "https", VS Code showed me the auto-complete options for the various schemas, so I just picked the one closest to the one you had originally put up... lol.

Answer (score 3):

I created a repository with a starter file to add the container at-rule and properties following [starball's method](/a/76125894/11107541).

https://github.com/wileycoyote78/custom-css/tree/main

Comment: cool. I didn't try it out, but the other improvements you made adding related properties looks good. see my comment [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/170589#issuecomment-1596265237)

Comment: I just tried it out, and it made the warnings go away. Thank you!

Comment: Awesome! Finally I make something that actually helps people... lol.